# cauchy sequence on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

i want to show that $\mathbb{R}$ with the following metric : $d_1(x,y)=|x^3-y^3|$ is complete. I think a good way to show it is to show that a sequence which is Cauchy for $d_1$ will also be Cauchy for the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ but i'm not able to write it properly. More precisely i want to write
$$|x^3-y^3|=|x-y||x^2+xy+xy^2|$$

and thus get $d(x,y)=\frac{d_1(x,y)}{|x^2+xy+y^2|}$ but i'm not able to ensure that if $d_1(x_m,x_n)\leq \varepsilon$ for $n$ and $m$ sufficiently large, then $d(x_m,x_n)\leq \varepsilon$ also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\left ( x_n \right )_{n\geq 1} $ is Cauchy in $d_1$ then $\left ( x_n ^{\frac {1}{3}} \right )_{n\geq 1}$ is Cauchy in $d$, and that's basically all you need.

Comment: then it suffices to say that $x_n^{\frac{1}{3}}$ converges toward $x$, and thus by continuity $x_n$ converges toward $x^9$ for $d_1$ since $x\mapsto x^9$ is continue for $d$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon >0$.

We have $d_1(x,y)=|x^3-y^3|$. Suppose $\left \{ x_n \right \}_{n\geq 0}$ is Cauchy in $d_1$. Then, $|x_n^3-x_m^3|<\epsilon $ for all $n,m$ large enough. But this says now that the sequence $\left \{ x^3_n \right \}_{n\geq 0}$ is Cauchy in $d$, the usual metric. Therefore, there is a $y\in \mathbb R$ such that $x^3_n\rightarrow y$. Write $y$ as $x^3$ for some $x\in \mathbb R$ (it is always possible to do this since $t\mapsto t^3$ is bijective) and now note that we have 
$d_1(x_n,x)=|x_n^3-x^3|\rightarrow 0$ which is what we want.

Comment: but here you suppose that the sequence is cauchy for d, while i want to show that $(\mathbb{R},d_1)$ is complete, i.e. i should start with a cauchy sequence for $d_1$.

Comment: @user270470 sorry I misread the problem. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence that is Cauchy in $d_1$ is Cauchy in $d$. See here [An Algebraic Proof that $|y^3 - x^3| \ge |(y - x)|^3/4 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533407/an-algebraic-proof-that-y3-x3-ge-y-x3-4#1533418) for a proof that  $|x_n^3 - x_m^3| \lt \epsilon \implies |x_n - x_m| \lt (4\epsilon)^{1/3}$.

Therefore the sequence has a limit $x$ in $d$ (because $\mathbb{R}$ is complete with $d$) and if $|x_n - x| \to 0$ then so does $|x_n^3 - x^3| $, so the Cauchy sequence has a limit in $d_1$.